# C# WPF DataGrid delete per selected items

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid which was declated in xaml called "DataGridUsers" I want to delete the values selected but how do I do that?

Here are my codes

```
    private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataGridUsers.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There is no selected rows!");// show a message here to inform
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DataGrid item in DataGridUsers.SelectedItems)
            {
                DataGridUsers.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to delete the values I select in the DataGrid that I have but I cant seem to do it.

Comment: whenever I  select an item from the grid then click the button it gives me this error 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid'.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SelectedIndex`

```
while (DataGridUsers.SelectedItems.Count > 0){
  DataGridUsers.Items.RemoveAt(DataGridUsers.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: it says, DataGrid Does not contain defirinition for rows.

Comment: still the same error saying it does not contain "rows"

Comment: @AubreyIvanApungan try  DataGridUsers.Items.RemoveAt(DataGridUsers.SelectedIndex);

Comment: it has no red lines but it when I clicked the button it gives this error 'Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.'

Comment: do a google search, you will see the answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataGridUsers.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is no selected rows!");// show a message here to inform
    }
    else
    {
        DataView dataView = DataGridUsers.ItemsSource as DataView;
        if (dataView != null)
        {
            for (int i = DataGridUsers.SelectedItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                DataRowView drv = DataGridUsers.SelectedItems[i] as DataRowView;
                if (drv != null)
                {
                    dataView.Table.Rows.Remove(drv.Row);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```